# JScrollPane doesn't update properly

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, tree, jtable

I have to insert new products in a JTable such that after pressing the "Add product" button, the table should update itself the new data provided. All the products are written into a file and read from it when printing out the table. The problem is that my table just stays the same and only after I exit the GUI application and enter again I can see the new updated JTable.

Here's the relevant code from the GUI class:

```
private class ManageProductsListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ...
            addProductBtn.addActionListener(new AddProductListener());
            removeProductBtn.addActionListener(new RemoveProductListener());
            manageProductsPanel.add(warehouse);
            manageProductsPanel.setVisible(true);
            finalPanel.add(manageProductsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
    }

    private class AddProductListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ...
                manageProductsPanel.remove(warehouse);
                Product product = new Product(insertProductName.getText(), Integer.parseInt(insertPrice.getText()), Integer.parseInt(insertStock.getText()));
                warehouse.addProduct(product);
                warehouse.writeFile();
                warehouse.printProducts();
                manageProductsPanel.add(warehouse);
                ... 
        }
    }
```

And here's a part from the Warehouse class:

```
public class Warehouse extends JPanel {
    ...        
    private TreeSet<Product> products = new TreeSet<Product>();
    private JTable productsTable;
    private Object[][] data;
    private String[] columns = {"Product name", "Price", "In stock", "Understock", "Overstock"};

    public Warehouse() {
    }

    public void addProduct(Product newProduct) {
        products.add(newProduct);
    }

    public void writeFile() {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("products.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);


            Iterator<Product> i = products.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                oos.writeObject(i.next());
            }
            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void readFile() {
        ...
    }

    public void printProducts() {
        data = new Object[products.size()][5];
        Iterator<Product> iterator = products.iterator();
        int i = 0;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Product p = iterator.next();
            data[i][0] = p.getProductName();
            data[i][1] = p.getPrice();
            data[i][2] = p.getStock();
            data[i][3] = p.checkUnderstock();
            data[i][4] = p.checkOverstock();
            i++;
        }
        createTable();
    }

    public void createTable() {
        productsTable = new JTable(data, columns);
        productsTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(600, 200));
        productsTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(productsTable);
        add(scroll);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant add a comment, so I have to post it as an answer. Have you tried to revalidate your panel after you add the table?

```
manageProductsPanel.revalidate()
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, but when I call this method I keep getting new tables. For example if I add a new product a new table appears; if I add another new product another new table appears and so on. The new tables don't even fit in the panel

Comment: This seems to happen because on your createTable method you add a new table but do not remove the older one.

Comment: How can I remove the older one?

Comment: By the looks of it, you should hold a reference to scroll instead of making it local to the method and call `remove(scroll)` at the beginning of the method. Dont forget to revalidate, you always have to revalidate a container when adding components to it once its already displayed

Comment: Don't keep creating new JTable and JScrollPane components. Don't keep adding and removing components. You should either update the existing TableModel by adding a new row to the model, or create a completely new TableModel and add the model to the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
    products.add(newProduct);
```

You should not be updating the products TreeSet. This does not update the data in the TableModel so of course the table is not updated. The data should only be contained in the TableModel and all updates to the data should be done directly to the TableModel.

Therefore you need a custom TableModel that can hold Product objects.

Check out the [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a generic TableModel that allows you to store custom objects. The `JButtonTableModel.java` code then shows how you can extend the RowTableModel to support your custom object.

Then when you create a new Product you just use the addRow(...) method of your newly created ProductTableModel.

Edit:

The answer above is the proper solution. You should never keep two copies of the data.

> I add another new product another new table appears and so on

That is because your Warehouse class is a JPanel which uses a FlowLayout, so when you keep adding components to it the panel just keep growing.

The solution is to NOT keep creating new components. Then is no need to keep creating a new JTable and JScrollPanse when you add new Products.

Instead, when you create the Warehouse class you create the table and the ScrollPane. The table will be empty.

Then when you add a Product to the product list you can create a new DefaultTablModel. Then you just use the `table.setModel(...)` method to update the table. Now the table will repaint itself with the new data.

Comment: He is building table later, with JTable constructor where you pass data Table and column table, its legal...

Comment: The data in the table is actually updated, because I save it into a file right after I add it to the products TreeSet. The main idea of this application is to use a TreeSet, so I shouldn't use something else

Answer (score 0):

Another solution maybe painless would be to reset the model of the table after the update:

```
productsTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, columns));
```